# I keep getting double results.

Tags: php, mysqli

I am an amateur programmer, and I just don't know what's wrong with my query. I want to get stuff out of the database for my landing page, but if I have multiple genres, I get multiple results. I think it has something to do with my query. Bear in mind, I'm not good at programming, nor am I good at SQL I have a table with films called 'films', the primary key is 'id', the table 'genres' has 'genreid' as primary key, and 'filmgenre' (where I inner join) has 'filmgenreid' as primary key. My code:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET["id"])){
            $filmid = $_GET["id"];
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *
                       FROM filmgenre INNER JOIN genres ON
                       genres.genreid=filmgenre.genreid INNER JOIN
                       films ON films.id=filmgenre.id WHERE films.id = '$filmid'");

            while($film = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
                <img class="filmimage" src="<?php echo $film["plaatje"] ?>" />
               <h2 class="filmtitle"><?php echo $film["titel"] ?></h2><br>
                <p class="tijdsduur">Tijdsduur: <?php $film["tijdsduur"] ?> minuten.</p>
                <iframe width="854" height="480" src="<?php echo $film["trailer"] ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p class="beschrijving"> <?php echo $film["voorwoord"] ?></p>
                <p class="producent">Producent <?php echo $film["producent"] ?>.</p>
                <p class="auteurs">Auteurs: <?php echo $film["auteurs"] ?>.</p>
                <p class="jaar"><?php echo $film["jaar"] ?>.</p>
                <?php echo $film["hoofdpersonen"] ?>
                <?php

            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong.";
        }
        ?>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That did the trick!

Comment: You can accept ans if this worked by clicking right tick mark. So that other know that this question is resovled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by`,

```
  WHERE films.id = '$filmid'" group by films.id;
```

Comment: I'd add a note about SQL injections as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cant really understand what you want exactly but could you give an example of what you should expect plus what you are getting instead

```
SELECT * FROM filmgenre fg INNER JOIN genres g ON fg.genreid =g.genreid
INNER JOIN  films f ON fg.id = f.id WHERE f.id = '$filmid' GROUP BY g.genreid";
```